# Angular 8 HttpClient GET response not returning the custom headers

Tags: angular

im trying to get the response header after http request and i cant get it...

```
headers: HttpHeaders;
httpOptions;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }).set("x-auth-token", token);

    this.httpOptions = {
    headers: this.headers,
    responseType: "text" as "json",
    observe: "response"
};}


test<T>(url: string) {
    return this.http.get<T>(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((res: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        console.log(res.headers.keys())
      }))
  }
```

im trying to get this:[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30yLc.png)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this: [Get-Full-Response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

I tried this code here and it works:

```
    this.http.get(this.url, { observe: `response` })
    .subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
```

I used subscribe instead of pipe. 
This was the response:

[Response printed on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb4Qe.png)

I'm not sure if this was helpfull.

Comment: its doing the same with pipe but i cant access to the specific heDER